# Algorithms to approximate a Riemann integrable function by a piecewise constant function

Tags: approximation-algorithms

We know that any general function that is Riemann integrable can be approximated to arbitrary precision by piecewise constant functions. So in this regard, I was looking for references on algorithms (and info on the corresponding query complexity since I assume it should be query-based) that when given a non-negative and non-atomic Riemann integrable function $f$ defined on the interval [0, 1] and an $\epsilon > 0$, outputs a piecewise constant function $g$ such that $ \forall I$, where $I$ is an interval in $[0,1], \int_I f(x) dx \leq \int_I g(x) dx \leq \int_I f(x) dx + \epsilon$.

**Edit 1:** Added that the function $f$ is non-negative and non-atomic.

**Edit 2:** Based on discussion in the comments, changed the question to "outputs a piecewise constant function $g$ such that $ \forall I$, where $I$ is an interval in $[0,1]$, $\int_I f(x) dx \leq \int_I g(x) dx \leq \int_I f(x) dx + \epsilon$".